# C# How to display 2 array in sequence with using two "for" loop?

Tags: c#

I am new to programming.

Let say i have

```
arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
arr2 = {+, - , *, /, =}
```

How can i display this two array in sequence by using two for loop in the form like this.

```
1+2-3*4/5=
```

Comment: Can we know what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Try to not focus to much on how you want it, rather on what you want when asking a question, so we can help you better.

Comment: To add to @Mafii comment, this is called a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) , or at least it looks like so. In my opinion, using 2 for loops seems a wrong tool for that. One `for`loop should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

A bit strange question but here you go...

```
string Result = string.Empty;

for (int i=0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j=i; j == i; j++)
    {
        Result += arr1[i]+arr2[j];
    }
}

Console.Write(Result);
```

Comment: This will not produce the desired result at all.

Comment: I tested it and it does, in fact, produce the expected output - it's just an odd way of writing it. In fact, the inner for loop is completely pointless (j == i in every possible case).

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need 2 `for` loops for this task?

```
  string[] arr1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
  string[] arr2 = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "="};

  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
  {
    Console.Write(arr1[i]);
    Console.Write(arr2[i]);
  }
```

This - of course - assumes, that `arr1` and `arr2`have the same length (number of elements).

EDIT

To display the result in a textbox you will require a variable:

```
string[] arr1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
string[] arr2 = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "="};

string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
  result += arr1[i] + arr2[i]; // TxtDisplay.AppendText(arr1[i] + arr2[i])

TxtDisplay.Text = result;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In case i would like to display in a textbox, what should i do?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Instead of writing the text to console you could append it to a string variable and write the string to the text box:

string text = string.Empty()
for( ... )
{
  text += arr1[i]; 
  text += arr2[i];
}
textBox1.Text = text;

or without the string variable:

for(...)
{
  textBox1.Text += arr1[i];
  textBox1.Text += arr2[i];
}

I assume that your textbox is called textBox1 here - exchange the name for your textbox name.

Comment: I have another question, how can I convert "result" to double and get the answer of the equation? I tried using Convert.ToDouble(result) but not works

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? Please give us some more pointers in the right direction. C# is not interpreted and has therefore a hard time interpreting strings to form an equation and print a result accordingly. Do you want to build a calculator application or something?

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky, but take a look at this :-)

```
var arr1 = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var arr2 = new[] {'+', '-', '*', '/', '='};
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(arr1.Length, arr2.Length); i++)
    Console.Write("{0}{1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
for (; false;) ;//second loop, as you wish
```

In production code, during optimization phase, you can remove second loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr1 = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var arr2 = new[] {"+", "-", "*", "/", "="};


for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length;i++)
{
    Console.Write(arr1[i]);

    for (;i<arr2.Length;)
    {
        Console.Write(arr2[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

produces

```
1+2-3*4/5=
```

Answer (score 1):

Koby is right, but you could do it slightly faster in this particular case. Since the arrays are the same size, you need one less loop. Of course, if the arrays are of different lengths then this will not work properly.

```
string Result = string.Empty;
for (int i=0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    Result += arr1[i]+arr2[i];
Console.WriteLine(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the LINQ extensions [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

```
var combined = arr1.Zip( arr2, (a1, a2) => a1+a2 );
var result = combined.Aggregate( (agg, item ) => agg + item );
// Display result whereever you like
Console.WriteLine( result );
```